# Simultaneous Dev and Prod versions beta-testing on a single android device

Tags: android, google-play, android-flavors

I want to run Beta testing version and Prod version on the same Android device.

I found solution with using different applicationId and the Flavors. It works perfect!

But, as I obtain different packages by different applicationId: `com.example.app.dev` & `com.example.app` - Play Market doesn't allow to upload file with package `com.example.app.dev` as beta of application with prod applicationId: `com.example.app`

Due this I create another PlayStore listing for `com.example.app.dev`. But it is obviously crooked manner.

Is there exist a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way around this if you want to use the play store. There are other solutions like Crashlytics is free and it allows you to have both apps installed using flavors.